# Stop the recursive function when it reaches high depth in c

Tags: c, recursion

I want to stop the recursive function when it reaches 3000 depth. how do I do it?

```
 void DFS(bool M[][COL], int row, int col) 
    { 
        short k;

        M[row][col] = 0; 

        for (k = 0; k < 4; k++){
            if(k==0){
                if (isSafe(M, row , col - 1) ){
                    DFS(M, row , col - 1);
                }
            }
            if(k==1){
                if (isSafe(M, row , col + 1) ){         

                   DFS(M, row , col + 1);
                }
            }
            if(k==2){
                if (isSafe(M, row + 1, col) ){          
                    DFS(M, row + 1, col);
                }
            }
            if(k==3){
                if (isSafe(M, row - 1 , col) ){         
                    DFS(M, row - 1, col);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

When I added the counter, I tried to return it when it was 3000, but I can't say I was very successful.

I have 512 * 512 matrix and I am looking for an island in this matrix. The recursive function gives the error if one of the island's area is more than 10000 units.

Comment: Where is your return statement? I don't see where this function ever is returning anything? Is this your actual code?

Comment: *How* did you add your counter? What does it do?

Comment: Where is the code with which you try to determine the depth of 3000? I would expect a depth counter, an `if` checking it and a return without recursion.

Comment: I'm moving in the matrix, so I don't need the return value. For example, if matrix [i] [j] = 1 and zero are covered, it stops because no IF condition is provided.

Comment: Can you show us the `isSafe` function? Is that where you are checking the condition for `1`? Also, the line `M[row][col] = 0;` at the top is very suspicious to me. I would not expect a function that is performing a depth first search to modify the array entries as it is searching.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a loop. It would be simpler to execute four `ifSafe` statements in succession.

Comment: I am still not following what the actual goal of this method is as it never returns anything. In looking at the complete code you linked, it still doesn't make sense. You end up checking the same location multiple times, which seems unnecessary and since you never return anything from this search method, you basically just perform the search and dump the results on the floor and since every node you visit gets its value set to 0, I am just not following what your actual goal is.

Comment: because I'm checking 4 directions @WeatherVane

Comment: @XLVII - But you don't need the for loop to do that. The for loop is just adding unnecessary overhead. You can just have 4 sequential if statements (see Tudors answer)

Comment: @XLVII of course, and you can remove a loop and 4 loop var conditionals as shown in an answer.

Comment: it finds values that are interconnected in four directions and all of them are 0.

Comment: @XLVII If you remove the `for` line and all four `if (k == …)` lines, and their associated closing `}` lines, but keep the inner `if (isSafe(…)) { … }`s, it will do exactly the same thing as it does currently, but at a considerably lower WTF factor. =)

Answer (score 6):

> I want to stop the recursive function when it reaches 3000 depth

A general solution to this is to add a "depth" argument to the function, and pass `depth + 1` to each recursive call (or `remaining_depth - 1` if you want to count backwards). To hide this from an outward-facing API, make the public function – without the depth argument – simply call the actual function with the initial value for `depth`.

For example:

```
#define MAX_DEPTH 3000

static void dfs_(bool M[][COL], int row, int col, int depth) {
    if (!isSafe(M, row, col)) { return; }
    M[row][col] = 0;
    if (depth >= MAX_DEPTH) { return; }
    dfs_(M, row, col - 1, depth + 1);
    dfs_(M, row, col + 1, depth + 1);
    dfs_(M, row - 1, col, depth + 1);
    dfs_(M, row + 1, col, depth + 1);
}

void DFS(bool M[][COL], int row, int col) {
    dfs_(M, row, col, 1);
}
```

Comment: I personally would have preferred starting with `depth = 0` and comparing `> MAX_DEPTH`, feels more C-like to me... Still, +1 from me.

Comment: @Aconcagua If you both start from zero and compare `> MAX_DEPTH`, it would (if otherwise unchanged) go two deeper than `MAX_DEPTH`. That is, `0` … `3000` (which is 3001 levels, counting the first) all make the recursive calls, then `3001` (which would be the 3002th level) is still processed itself (before the `if (depth >= MAX_DEPTH)` line) but doesn't recurse further. Starting from `0` but keeping the comparison would be arguably ok if the depth is defined as "distance from start", though.

Comment: Ah, should have been (in my comment) `if(depth < MAX_DEPTH) { /*recursive calls*/ }`.

Comment: *'matter of opinion'* - sure. Well, that's why I started with *'I personally'*...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the for is pointless if you took the time to write four different if's for the neighbours. They will each execute once anyways.

```
void DFS(bool M[][COL], int row, int col) 
{ 
    static int depth = 0;
    ++depth;
    if (depth > 3000)
    {
        --depth;
        return;
    }

    M[row][col] = 0; 
    if (isSafe(M, row , col - 1) )
        DFS(M, row , col - 1);

    if (isSafe(M, row , col + 1) )       
       DFS(M, row , col + 1);

    if (isSafe(M, row + 1, col) )     
        DFS(M, row + 1, col);

    if (isSafe(M, row - 1 , col) )        
        DFS(M, row - 1, col);

    --depth;
    return;
}
```

This should work. The depth variable will count the number of calls to DFS, and everytime it returns, you decrement the value. **However this is not be the best approach** because there are cases where it may cause problems. The only one I can think of is when you use exceptions. Because they will exit your function and not decrement the depth variable.

Another approach is keeping the depth as a parameter, but it makes the function verbose to call.

Comment: Making depth static works, but usually you want a recursive function to be re-entrant, and thus pass the depth.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have `!isSafe()` call at the beginning? You will get same results, if you have with calls to `isSafe()` inside if statements. By moving `isSafe ()` at the beginning you improve code readability by avoiding duplicate code, and you are less prone to errors. This way it will execute only return statement nothing else.

Now comes the part you were asking for depth.

```
void DFS(bool M[][COL], int row, int col)  {
    static int depth = 0;

    if ( !isSafe(M, row , col) || depth > 3000)
        return;

    depth++;

    short k;

    M[row][col] = 0; 

    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        switch (k)
            case 0 :
                DFS(M, row , col - 1);
                break;
            case 1 :
               DFS(M, row , col + 1);
               break;
            case 2 :
                DFS(M, row + 1, col);
                break;
            case 3 :
                DFS(M, row - 1, col);
                break;
            default :
                return;
}
```

Now that I think I do agree with @Tudors point about `for` loop, but I will leave this here as a way to rewrite your code using much better syntax.

Comment: I agree with you about the `isSafe`, but why, oh why, do you want to have the same pointless `for` loop as the question? =)